# ¿Como procesar archivos CSV con Django, despues de ser importado?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Necisito una explicación u orientación de los pasos de como procesar un archivo csv, se importarlo con el campo FileField de los modelos de Django pero necesito que la información del CSV re replique en la bases de datos. Agradezco su colaboración.

Answer (score 1):

Para procesar el CSV tendrías que generar una función manualmente utilizando alguna librería, como https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Si ya estás utilizando la carga del CSV via un FileField, podrías hacer la llamada a esta función cuando tu objeto se haya guardado. Algo así como:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=models.TuModelo)
def csv_handler(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    # Y aquí haces el tratamiento del CSV con la librería anterior
```

De todas formas, no tengo muy claro por qué almacenas el CSV en un FileField. Yo personalmente preferiría cargar el CSV con un formulario `forms.Form` en lugar de con un `forms.ModelForm`, y hacer el tratamiento del CSV directamente en la función `save` del formulario, o bien en la vista.

Algo así:

```
# views.py
import csv
from django.views import generic

class ManageCSV(generic.FormView):
    form_class = forms.ManageCSVForm
    ...

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # Gestiona aquí tu CSV con la librería anterior
        # Podría ser algo así:
        with open(form.cleaned_data['csv_file'], 'rb') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
            for row in reader:
                TuModelo.objects.create( ... )

        return super(ManageCSV, self).form_valid(form)

# forms.py
class ManageCSVForm(forms.Form):
    csv_file = forms.FileField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ManageCSVForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Fieldset(
                u'',
                'csv_file'
            )
        )
        self.helper.layout.append(Submit('guardar', 'Guardar'))
```

Está todo sin probar, porque tampoco das mucha información, pero la cosa iría por ahí. Es bastante sencillo.

Comment: Gracias por el aporte voy  ha probar procesandolo desde la vista. Cualquier cosa te cuento.